# Where to find the Cray arithmetic library?

Tags: c, simulator, cray

Given a [Cray simulator](https://github.com/andrastantos/cray-sim)
and a [pre-installed UniCOS HD image](https://archive.org/download/uni-cos-10.0.1.2-linux-x-86-64.7z/UniCOS-10.0.1.2_linux_x86_64.7z), attempting to compile Steven Pemberton's [ENQUIRE](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/enquire/enquire.c) (literally, the second thing to try after "Hello, Cray") fails with

```
CC-1153 cc: INTERNAL File = enquire.c, Line = 1182
  PRINTMSG:  internal error from arith or backend
```

because of

```
282941972 CPU0: XA: 0x1A IBA: 0x00D56000 SYSCALL: 5 ??(0x0001BAE3 (0x00D012E3) "/opt/ctl/craylibs/craylibs/arith" , 0x0000000000000000 (0))
282942122 CPU0: SYSCALL: 5 ?? returning 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (18446744073709551615)
282942128 CPU0: XA: 0x1A IBA: 0x00D56000 SYSCALL: 5 ??(0x0001BAE3 (0x00D012E3) "/lib/arith" , 0x0000000000000000 (0))
282942302 CPU0: SYSCALL: 5 ?? returning 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (18446744073709551615)
```

That is, some dynamically-loaded arithmetic library is not found in either of two expected locations.

Does it mean that [The Cray Files](https://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/the-cray-files/) are incomplete, or the pre-installed UniCOS is misconfigured/corrupt, or something else?
Could anyone please try the experiment independently (assuming copious free time, of course)?

---

JFYI, according to Dhrystone, the simulator runs on Raspberry Pi 5 at an approximately native speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turned out, the required arithmetic library is present in the filesystem, though at different place:

```
# ls -l /usr/gen/lib/arith
-rwxr-xr--   1 bin      bin       326028 Dec  4  2022 /usr/gen/lib/arith
# file /usr/gen/lib/arith
/usr/gen/lib/arith:     executable CRAY-YMP stripped
```

With this file copied to /lib/arith, the C compiler works as expected. I was able to compile enquire.c and run it.

It is possible to extract file `arith` directly from the Unicos CD image.

1. Download file [cray-cd1.iso](https://archive.org/download/cray-cd1/cray-cd1.iso)
2. Unpack it and extract file UNICOS_exe/uni_22.gzc
3. Rename it as uni_22.bin.gz
4. Run `gzip -d uni_22.bin.gz` to unpack into uni_22.bin
5. Build utility bcpio_extractor from [sources](https://github.com/andrastantos/cray-sim/tree/master/simulator/bcpio_extractor)
6. Run `bcpio_extractor uni_22.bin` to unpack all files
7. The arithmetic library is present there as usr/gen/lib/arith

Comment: Really nice answer.  I like that it has both the short answer, and the longer other way to accomplish it.